# WP7 : SL/XNA : display XNA data in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

I am working on a Silverlight/XNA game. Having structure like this :

- My **GamePlay** class is inherited from **InGamePage**.
- Where **InGamePage** is  inherited from **PhoneApplicationPage**.
- InGamePage has a OnLayoutUpdated method to render SL controls(using UIElementRenderer ).

This is as per SL/XNA [code sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/model_viewer_demo)

Everything is working fine till I decided to create a textblock in gamepage.xaml . I want that textBlock to show the some static game variables( like distance covered by hero).

Now where should I write this line :

```
debugTextBlock.Text = GameData.data.distanceCovered;
```

so that textblock shows the current values.
(I tried to hook a LayoutUpdate but its throwing Application_UnhandledException saying "Layout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete.")

Any hint/link is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the exception that is being thrown?

Comment: @Rowland edited the question, well the exception is ("Layout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete.")

Comment: Did you see [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/636245/50447)?

Comment: that didn't helped much @Rowland, I guess its SL+XNA that's resisting two controls to render simultaneously. Because if I try to update the debugTextBlock.Text on any event its working fine.

Comment: It would help if you explained where you are trying to set the text from -- if it's from your overridden `OnLayoutUpdated`  I could understand that you're trying to change something during render (which could change the positions of a bunch of other things) - you've already spotted that if you change where you update the text, it'll work, so that sounds like your solution.

Comment: Ok let me make this more clear. In my SL+XNA game SL controls are drawn using UIElementRenderer and XNA game using spritebatch. Now I want my game variables to be drawn on a scroll-able textblock which shows me current values. Right now values are updated only when I tap on the textblock(as i assign text on the gotfocus event.)

Answer (score 0):

I think that simply using Dispatcher might work:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
{
debugTextBlock.Text = GameData.data.distanceCovered; 
});
```

Comment: sorry if I am sounding novice but where should is perform this code. I check tried this thread also (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320181/multiple-asynchronous-ui-updates-in-silverlight) but all vain.

Comment: Since you provided Exception beeing thrown my answer does not match your problem at all.
Is debugTextBlock fixed size or it changes size accordingly to content inside?